# Argument for Emission theory or extramission theory

Tags: philosophy-of-science

I read on Wikipedia and T.S.Kuhn's book that [Emission theory or extramission theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emission_theory_(vision)) prevailed for around two thousand years.
I want to ask that if light beams came out of eyes then how was the fact that "We do not see the same object during night time, while we see them during the day" was explained?

Comment: See this paper about [GALEN’S THEORY OF VISION](https://representationandreality.gu.se/digitalAssets/1684/1684161_ierodiakonou---on-galen-s-theory-of-vision.pdf): the theory is quite complex; at page 19 for Galen's view about  the role of sunlight as a necessary condition for visual perception.

Comment: This looks useful. Thank you! I'll read it in detail.

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.